# Look for an value in a sheet count it and paste the result in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am having two Sheets sheet1 and sheet2

In sheet1 , in column AX I have my present week printed using an formula. I am looking for the sheet1, column T and U and Count the number of 1'S in both the columns.

the counted number of 1's of both the columns should be pasted in sheet2 looking into the week of sheet1 in column AX. if the column AX has week number 24, then it should run along the sheet2, column A for 24 and paste the Count value of T in column B and Count value of U in column C, and calculate the percentage for both and Paste in C and D.

I tried through a code, I am often getting it as 0,I am struck where I am wrong. Ist neither checking the Count nor weeks.

```
Sub test()
Dim col As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim T As Integer
Dim U As Integer
Dim wk As String

Set sh1 = Sheets("BW")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Results")



For Each col In sh2.Columns 'This loops through all populated columns in row one
    If sh2.Cells(1, col.Column).Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If

    wk = sh2.Cells(1, col.Column).Value

    For Each rw In sh1.Rows
        If sh1.Cells(rw.row, 50).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

        If sh1.Cells(rw.row, 50) = wk And sh1.Cells(rw.row, 20) = 1 Then
            T = T + 1
        End If

        If sh1.Cells(rw.row, 50) = wk And sh1.Cells(rw.row, 21) = 0 Then
            U = U + 1
        End If
    Next rw

sh2.Cells(2, col.Column) = T 'put counters into 2nd and 3rd row under each week, you can adjust this to put the number in a different cell.
sh2.Cells(3, col.Column) = U

T = 0 'reset counters to start looking at next week.
U = 0

Next col

End Sub
```

[image: Resembels sheet1, where i have my data]

[image: Resembels sheet2, where I have the column A already filled, Need to fill column B, C , D and E. B and C are the Count values from sheet1 column T and U, D and E are the percentage values from column b and c of sheet2.]
[image: Clarification img: for eg, this is how the sheet2 Looks. I already made an evalaluation last before week.now i am running a formula in sheet1, which gives current week in AX. SO, the sheet2 runs through column a, identifies the same week as sheet1 and add the Count value only in the current week, it does not Change the value of earlier week or next week.currently the code Returns 0, in all the weeks and Returns the Count value for current week. i want it to return only for current week.]

Comment: @pnuts Sorry. I dint understand what you mean

Comment: Many of your previous questions have answers that you haven't yet accepted - did they not provide solutions to the issues?

Comment: @paulbica No, they are not the solution that i am expecting. and most which i have the solution, i have accepeted it and marked it green.

Comment: @paulbica could you help me to provide answer for this Situation or what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Can you show a small sample of how sheet1 looks now, and how sheet2 should look? current data and expected result - I'd like to duplicate what you're doing

Comment: Sure @paulbica I will update it with my post

Comment: @paulbica I have added the requirement.

Comment: I'm in the chat room now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from the question that sheet "Results" for a given week indicated in column A, shows in column B & C count of 1's in column T & U of the other sheet respectively.

One approach to solve this is that for each row in "Results" sheet, the counter looks into all rows of "BW" sheet for that week indicated in column "AX" to get the count from column T & U.

This'll give some idea:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, cntT As Integer, cntU As Integer, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Results")
    Sheets("BW").Select
    For i = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(1))
        If ws.Range("A" & i) = Val(Format(Now, "ww")) Then Exit For
    Next i
    ws.Range("B" & i & ":" & "E" & i).ClearContents
    cntT = 0
    cntU = 0
    For j = 5 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(50))
        If ws.Range("A" & i) = Range("AX" & j) And Range("AA" & j) <> "" Then
            If Range("T" & j) = 1 Then cntT = cntT + 1
            If Range("U" & j) = 1 Then cntU = cntU + 1
        End If
    Next j
    If cntT <> 0 Then ws.Range("B" & i) = cntT
    If cntU <> 0 Then ws.Range("C" & i) = cntU
    If cntT + cntU <> 0 Then
        ws.Range("D" & i) = cntT / (cntT + cntU)
        ws.Range("E" & i) = cntU / (cntT + cntU)
    End If
    ws.Range("D" & i & ":E" & i).NumberFormat = "0%"
End Sub
```

Update: as per subsequent discussion with @Mikz below criteria added to the above updated code:

1. it only overwrites current week, so for Jul 2, 2017 it'll only overwrite the current week of 27 if found in `column A` of `Results` sheet

   if the is output is 0, it will leave the target cells as blank

   if respective cell of the AA column of "BW" sheet is blank, that row won't be counted for 1s

   sheet "BW" data starts from row 5

Comment: the code, you have provided works great. but, i dont want the previous columns or the rest of columns in my sheet2 "result" to be evaluated as 0 .because this is a Kind of record for Evaluation. so i made an Evaluation  last week.and this week26  i am making an new Evaluation, means, i want the new Count values to be stored for the week and previous week should remain as it is.

Comment: sorry not very clear. you don't want result sheet evaluated as 0, so if the count is 0, shall it show in the result sheet as blank instead of 0? if you don't want any changes to the old data in result sheet, what's the identifier of new addition? an example will help clarify

Comment: i have added an clarification Image and description for that. may be that is clear. or i will explain in other words

Comment: Thank you @Curious for clarifying my issue. Thankful to you

Comment: With the above code, I am checking if the column AA is null, if null i dont want the Count value from T and U, if not null, then i Need the Count value from T and U. For this i used the line " If ws.Range("AA" & i) = "" Then
    GoTo nextrow ,  after for J= 2, I am getting an  error Label not defined

Comment: how to execute for this condition

Comment: if it's the AA column of Results sheet, the line `If ws.Range("A" & i) = Val(Format(Now, "ww")) Then Exit For` may be changed to `If ws.Range("A" & i) = Val(Format(Now, "ww")) And ws.Range("AA" & i) <> "" Then Exit For`

Comment: It is not in result sheet, it is in the BW sheet, where i am looking or Count value of column T and U . if the AA column is empty, I dont want to consider those rows, only when they are filled, i Need the Count value of T and U.

Comment: on a small note , the sht bw data starts from row 5.

Comment: Back again . I am getting wrong count value when I tried the same code. Can you help me to figure out?

Comment: hi, please explain in details. will take a look

Comment: Back again, I have a problem with the code, that I am getting runtime error . "Overflow" . Could you help :(

Comment: I posted in forum and no one could figure out the correct solution. , I hope you can help me